# Intento simplificar comprobacion

Tags: javascript, php, html, formularios

Buen dia, estoy creando una comprobacion de formulario y queria ver si habia alguna forma de simplificarlo, el codigo funciona
codigo php:

```
$validar_titulo = $_POST["tituloLibro"];
if(empty($validar_titulo)){
        $error = 'el titulo es necesario';
        ?>
        <script>
            let span = document.getElementById('errorSpanTitulo');
            span.innerHTML = "<?php echo '*' . ucfirst($error);?>";
            span.style.margin = "0 0 0 5px";
        </script>
        <?php
    }else{
        $titulo = $validar_titulo;
        ?>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('tituloLibro').value="<?php echo $titulo; ?>"
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

esto se repite con todos los campos del formulario, por lo que el codigo se hace extenso, si me falto agregar algo por favor digan, gracias.
otro ejemplo:

```
$validar_autor = $_POST["autorLibro"];

$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\sñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/";


if(empty($validar_autor) || !preg_match($pattern, $validar_autor)){
        $error = 'el autor es necesario';
        ?>
        <script>
        let span = document.getElementById('errorSpanAutor');
        span.innerHTML = "<?php echo '*' . ucfirst($error);?>";
        span.style.margin = "0 0 0 5px";
        </script>
        <?php
    }else{
        $autor = $validar_autor;
        ?>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('autorLibro').value="<?php echo $autor; ?>"
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Para escribir una buena respuesta habría que ver el tipo de _validaciones_ que realizas y entender el por qué las estás haciendo del lado del servidor. Para lo que muestras, la validación del lado del cliente suele ser suficiente y, de hecho, con el atributo `required` de la etiqueta `<input>`, no hace falta validación, el browser se encarga de _exigir_ que el campo tenga un valor. Así, el código en PHP se reduce a 0 líneas.

Comment: hola, en realidad le agregue la verificacion del lado del servidor porque lei que el required no era seguro, y este solo es el que tiene el empty, los demas tienen otras verificaciones como que tengan ciertos caracteres o que sean menores que x numero, ahora edito el post

Comment: ¿En qué sentido no es _seguro_ el required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290122/is-html5-input-required-a-secure-validation-technique

Comment: Obviamente debes hacer TODAS las validaciones de seguridad necesarias del lado del servidor, pero mi enfoque es distinto. Diría que para el usuario normal, haces todo _pretty_ del lado del cliente. Puedes valerte de javascript y bibliotecas para sacar mensajes de error vistosos, hacer recuadros en los campos con errores, etc. Del lado del servidor haces algo más simple, como un `if (!isset($_POST["tituloLibro"]) or (empty($_POST["tituloLibro"])) die("titulo requerido")`.

Comment: Tu usuario _normal_ nunca verá un error de estos, pues el cliente ha validado todo antes de hacer el post. Estos errores son para quién está automatizando el sitio (si lo permites), o para quien quiere abusar de él. Ninguno de estos no necesita los recuadritos bonitos y mensajes de error generados desde el servidor). Te repito, es mi enfoque y, en mi experiencia, es mucho más simple y elegante.

Comment: Y, para el cliente _normal_, required suele ser suficiente (obviamente no hablamos de la _seguridad_ del sistema, sino de la usabilidad del sitio).

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a intentar hacer las comprobaciones en js y despues hacer lo que dijiste en php. asi capaz pueda hacerlo mas estetico, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mezclando en el servidor las validaciones que necesariamente tiene que hacer este (en cuanto a integridad y seguridad), con la lógica de interacción con el usuario y ofrecerle mensajes de error y *ayudas* para que logre completar el formulario.

Si separas esto, vas a lograr tener un código mucho más simple, tanto del lado del servidor, como del lado del cliente, pues la intención de cada uno queda totalmente clara y no se mezclan cosas que debe hacer uno con las que debe hacer el otro, que es lo que observo en el código de ejemplo que publicas en la pregunta.

Del lado del servidor, debiera bastar con el equivalente a:

```
if (!isset($_POST["tituloLibro"]) or (empty($_POST["tituloLibro"])) die("titulo requerido")
```

Del lado del cliente, puedes asegurarte que el cliente *normal* nunca vea este feo mensaje de error, haciendo las validaciones necesarias, que pueden ser una combinación de reglas y validaciones activas realizadas con código.

De hecho, puedes querer usar alguna biblioteca de las muchas que hay especializadas en el tema, por ejemplo, te dejo aquí un ejemplo (muy sencillo) del uso de [validator.js](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/validator.js):

```js
const patternAutor = /^[a-zA-Z\sñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/;

var validator = new Validator({
  form: document.getElementById('form'),
  rules: {
    autor: {
      validate: (val) => ((val)&&(patternAutor.test(val))) ?'':'Caracteres inválidos en autor!'
    },
    email: {
      validate: (val) => val ? '' : 'Email requerido!',
    },
    password: {
      validate: (val) => (!val)||val.length<5||val.length>15?'longitud debe ser entre 5 y 15' : ''
    },
  }
});

validator.form.onsubmit = (evn) => {
  evn.preventDefault();
  const values = validator.getValues();
  if (Object.keys(validator.errorMessages).length===0) {
    console.log("todo OK", values);
  } else {
    console.log("errores: ", validator.errorMessages);
  }
}

validator.form.onreset = (evn) => {
  const data = validator.reset();
  console.log(data);
}
```

```css
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.statically.io/gh/jaywcjlove/validator.js/master/packages/core/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="autor">Autor:</label>
    <input type="text" name="autor" placeholder="" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">EMail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <button type="reset">Borrar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

En un sistema ya preparado para producción, esto estaría, obviamente, mucho más refinado.